# Java class name that starts with java

Tags: java

I have a java class that I am importing unfortunately named java.net_y.  My code compiles, but when I try to run it I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.net_y
```

I've read other threads about trying to override core java classes like java.io.....thats not what I am doing....this external class I have is just named badly.

Another thread mentioned reflection...not sure if that is required.

What can I do?

Comment: Maybe put that package in another? so it becomes mypackage.java.met_y

Answer (score 5):

> What can I do?

Rename that class.

Comment: Its not that simple...the class is actually a Web Service...generated from a WSDL.

Comment: You could also investigate using a custom class loader... I'm not leaving this as an answer because it's definitely not the right one ;-)

Comment: @Yusuf, can you re-generate the web service proxy from the WSDL, this time attempting to create the proxy class in a different package?

Comment: @Yusuf - then you'll need to redo the generation, configuring it so that the generated class gets a different package this time.  Or if it is "external" in the sense that someone else has given it to you, then tell *them* to regenerate it (because they've given you something unusable).

Comment: @Grundlefleck Wont help. You still need use `ClassLoader` to define the class, which will refuse.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin: good call, it seems the relevant parts needed to be overridden from `ClassLoader` are marked `final`. Yup, definitely not the right answer ;-)

Comment: @Grundlefleck: unfortunately, not even redefining the `java.lang.ClassLoader` (which I did with the `java.lang.instrument` API) works, because the JVM itself does the same check; the check implemented in `ClassLoader` is redundant :(

Answer (score 2):

If the class was generated from a web service WSDL, the best thing would be to regenerate it and forcing the package name to something else.
Most WSDL-to-java tools have parameters to let you do that.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use [Java Decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) to reverse engineer what you are importing, make the necessary changes and then recompile.

I am actually assuming that you are trying to import some sort of .jar file or something along those lines. If you are importing just one class, then all you need to do is to rename it.

Answer (score 0):

I should rename your class. You cannot put classes to java package. See

```
java.lang.ClassLoader#predefineClass()
```

This is a private method that performs the following check:

```
if ((name != null) && name.startsWith("java.")) {
    throw new SecurityException("Prohibited package name: " +
                name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf('.')));
}
```

As far as I understand this is exactly the exception you see.

Sometimes people have to override classes from JDK. It is not your case, but I'd like to mention it just in case. To do this you have to put this overridden class to

```
-Xbootclasspath
```

instead of regular

```
-classpath
```

when you are running your JVM